# user didn't choose the any account in google sign in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am facing an issue with signInWithGoogle, when a popup opens to choose an account, if a user does not select any account then GoogleSignIn().signIn(); does not give any response on how to tackle this issue.

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    String res = "Something went to worng";
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser?.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );
    if (credential == null) {
      return "some thing ";
    }
    try {
      UserCredential cred = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      res = "Success";
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
      print(err);
    }
    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return res;
  }
```

I am implementing in Flutter Firebase auth google sign in method. it works perfectly but the issue is that when the user presses on continue with Google popup will open for choose an account if the user presses the back button then GoogleSignIn().signIn(); does not give any response.

Answer (score 1):

You must check that the user should not be null when you get the credentials. The GoogleSignIn().signIn() method will return a GoogleSignInAccount if the user successfully signs in.

```
  Future signInWithGoogle() async { // Trigger the authentication flow String res = "Somthing went to worng"; final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

// Obtain the auth details from the request
try{
  
   final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  
   if(gUser != null)
  {
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
     
// Create a new credential
final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,);
if (credential == null) {
  return "some thing ";
}

  UserCredential cred = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  return "Success";
} 
}
  catch (err) {
   
    //Catch any errors here
}
// Once signed in, return the UserCredential
}
```